# Cant understand the error : OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, multithreading, class, sockets, tcp

After some research I found that it is related to the connection. The socket is getting closed before the connection request is coming. But why is it happening, I cant understand

I am getting an error in the server code:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

data = ''

# This thread manages the client connections
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):
   def __init__(self,conn,Address):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.conn = conn
       print("New connection added", Address)
   def run(self):
       print ("Connection from : ", Address)
       self.conn.send(bytes("You are connected to IIT H",'utf-8'))

# This thread takes care about recieving the contents of the .txt file
class RecieveThread(threading.Thread):       
   def __init__(self,conn,Address):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.conn = conn
   def run(self):
       print("This data is from Housekeeping unit: ",Address)
       data = self.conn.recv(1024).decode()
       print("The wastebin attributes are:  ",  data)

host = ''
port = 5000
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_socket.bind((host, port))

print("The IIT-H server is active")
print("Waiting for clients to connect")   

server_socket.listen(4)
conn, Address = server_socket.accept()
ClientThread(conn,Address).start()
RecieveThread(conn,Address).start()

conn.close()
```

Getting the error in the line:

```
data = self.conn.recv(1024).decode()
```

Kindly help me

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect the connection to be open? You explicitly close the connection in the last line, without waiting for the threads to finish or even start running.

Comment: My apologies that you could not understand the question. I am not expecting the connection to be always open. Although I have coded it so that once started the server is always listening. This exact same code was working fine, but suddenly throwing me this error. 

The socket is getting closed, before it is supposed to. The lines in class ReceiveThread are running fine upto:

print("This data is from Housekeeping unit: ",Address)

Comment: Let me rephrase: Why do you expect the socket to be in a readable state when using them in the threads? You can neither send nor recv on a closed socket, yet close the socket *immediately* after launching the threads.

Comment: Let me simplify: delete `conn.close()`.

Comment: Well, the thing is, this exact same code was working perfectly, I made some changes to it to test one thing. That did not work out. So I undid all the changes. After that it shoed error.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I did what you said, and on execution the code is giving me broken pipe error Infinitely

Comment: @MisterMiyagi If you observe my main program, I am starting the thread in main program.

Comment: Do you want me to upload the client code too

Comment: The relative timing of threads is arbitrary. Calling ``conn.close()`` after launching the thread *may or may not* close the connection before the threads try to use it (in my tests, it worked in 1 out of 10 cases). Removing ``conn.close()`` removed this race condition, and did not cause an error in this program - does the error occur in your client perhaps?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi No the client is working fine without throwing any error. Let me share the link to my other question, there my client code is also written:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357286/how-to-pass-objects-from-one-thread-class-to-another-thread-class-in-python

Comment: Again, when Sam removing `conn.close()`, the server receives the message from first client and stops listening. I dont want that and also previously it was not happening.

Comment: We can't say what happened previously - we can only say what happens now. Keeping ``conn.close()`` will *not* get your server to keep on listening, since both ``ClientThread.run`` and ``RecieveThread.run`` perform their action just once. Note that your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357286/how-to-pass-objects-from-one-thread-class-to-another-thread-class-in-python) also wraps the accept-startthread part in an infinite loop, both repeating the parts and never reaching the ``conn.close()``. Is that the initial state of your code?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I am a rookie, I wrote that code for 3 weeks.

Comment: Add the ``while True:`` loop again, then.

Comment: Added and working fine. And this leads me to my other question. Thanks a lot for your patience with me.